# How to set an array name via a NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, variables

I'm curious If it's possible to create a new array and set its pointer name via an NSString, if so how am i able to do this?

As I've tried

```
 NSArray *variableName = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

But that obviously doesn't work, does anyone have any idea how to set the name via a string?

Comment: Don't see an actual question here, but maybe others do?

Comment: The question and the code snippet seem totally unrelated.

Comment: @nhgrif I think OP is implying that the array's pointer name should be the value of a different variable.

Comment: Let me see if I get the question: you want to have a string that stores the variable name of a pointer that contains the data that should be stored in the array, is that what you want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The closest you could do is to store the `NSArray` in an `NSDictionary` with the string as a key.

Answer (score 0):

You can, you need to use the Objective-C runtime library. You can add properties and their backing fields at runtime. Too add a property look into the `class_addProperty` function.

This is the Apple doc. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/class_addProperty